# Secure payment using href

Tags: php, laravel, payment

I'm trying to implement payments into a Laravel 5.3 application but I'm not able to do that securely. I wan't to do it with [Datatrans](https://www.datatrans.ch/showcase/authorisation/redirect-mode), a Swiss E-Payment company.
The code to perform a payment looks like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Test redirect</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Test redirect</h1>

<a href="https://pilot.datatrans.biz/upp/jsp/upStart.jsp?merchantId=1100004624&refno=1337&amount=1000&currency=CHF&paymentmethod=ECA&paymentmethod=VIS&paymentmethod=AMX&paymentmethod=DIN&paymentmethod=DIS&paymentmethod=PAP&theme=DT2015">Pay</a>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I make sure the user can't change the URL and change the amount parameter to 1 CHF?
Or can I somehow redirect the user to this URL from the controller?

I'm totally confused at the moment. Probably it's way easier than I think...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a good answer would require a tutorial and not an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should redirect form the controller like so

```
return Redirect::to($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at `cURL`. Here a link to learn more about it. http://codular.com/curl-with-php

Use `$_SESSION` to pass your variables (price) from page to page

Good Luck